# Is the Java compiler allowed to be flow sensitive for static calls?

Tags: java, jls

Here's a brief example from the JLS section 8.4.8.2.

```
class Super {
    static String greeting() { return "Goodnight"; }
    String name() { return "Richard"; }
}
class Sub extends Super {
    static String greeting() { return "Hello"; }
    String name() { return "Dick"; }
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super s = new Sub();
        System.out.println(s.greeting() + ", " + s.name());
    }
}
```

According to the discussion of the example, the output of running `main()` will be "Goodnight, Dick". This is because static methods are called based on the static type of the variable/expression they are called on.

Here's my question: Any even moderately flow-sensitive compiler could figure out that the type of any object stored in `s` at the time of the call must always be `Sub`, so if the compiler were allowed to use that information, even calling static methods could have some of the feel of dynamic binding. Why is this not allowed? Does Java have the express goal that every compiler produces bytecode that behaves exactly the same or is there some other reason?

Comment: Absolutely, the JLS takes care that there is one and only one Java semantics.

Comment: Static members are not subject to subtyping rules. That's all. Allowing them to be invoked upon an expression instead of only the corresponding Type is a language flaw as far as I am concerned.

Comment: The designers and maintainers of Java have gone to great lengths (almost to a fault) to assure that all versions of Java behave exactly the same in all environments.  In the case of `invokestatic`, the bytecode takes only a class and method -- the ability to use an instance variable of the class is a sort of "syntactic sugar" on the part of the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact here `s.greeting()`is equivalent to `Super.greeting()` because `s` is defined to be `Super` and static methods do not care about class instances. They're class-wide as you surely know. So it directly makes no sense to call a static method from a class instance. And of course the instance `s` is a `Sub()` as you specified, so the non-static method `Sub.name()` is called.

From [Java official tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):

> You can also refer to static fields with an object reference like
>
> `myBike.numberOfBicycles`
>
> but this is discouraged because it does not make it clear that they
>   are class variables.

Allowing static methods to be class-instance wise would only make the code less readable, more arcane and harder to debug without really adding any useful feature.

Comment: Yes. I get it this far. My question was more along the lines of "since it's allowed to call static methods on expressions (here `s`), why no use the most specific static type known for `s` instead of the declared type? But I guess if Java insists on unique semantics, that's the answer.

Comment: In fact you should not use the instances to call static methods. IMHO that kind of ambiguity you're talking about would only make the code less readable and the language more arcane without really adding any useful feature.

Comment: And this is why you get a warning when you call a static method in a non-static context.  You shouldn't call it that way.  Not to mention, static methods are bound at compile time, where as instance methods can either be bound at compile time or at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It is not too java specific. Imagine your "intelligent" compilation with `s.getClass().greeting()` in:

```
class A extends Sub {
    static String greeting() { return "Allo"; }
}
class B extends Sub {
    static String greeting() { return "Brrr"; }
}
Super s = condition? new A() : new B();
assert s.greeting.equals(Sub.greeting()); // If compiler cannot infer condition.
```

Should the compiler do that across more than one source? Out of libraries, where the source code might not be available.

I rather think the fallacy in java is, that `s.greeting()` is allowed.

As there is no use for static inheritance, better not invent such a feature.